# Why does my vs-code container deployment to my GKE K8s cluster return "Does not have minimum availability"

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, containers, google-kubernetes-engine

So I am currently running a K8s GKE cluster. We have been successful in deploying images of basic full-stack websites to the cluster, however we have been trying to deploy Microsoft VSCode images from: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/main/containers/javascript-node

more specifically -- mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/javascript-node:16

and the image experiences "CrashLoopBackOff" and "Does not have minimum availability" issues. We're extremely lost on why this could be as we believe that we have enough memory to successfully deploy this. Any help is appreciated!

The specs are as follows:

```
type: zonal
zone: us-west1-a
release channel: regular channel
version: 1.19.9-gke.1900
total size: 3
machine-type: e2-medium
image-type: container-optimized os with containerd

(All 3 nodes have 940mCPU allocatable)
```

Our yaml file is as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vs-code-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vs-code-test
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vs-code-test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: vs-code
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/javascript-node:16
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: You would have to look at the log output and pod events. A program crashing can happen for many reasons.

Comment: @coderanger yeah we've been trying to pull up the log from our google cloud interface and it's giving us nothing. "No entries found"

Comment: Try `kubectl describe pod vs-code-deployment-[somerandomstuff]`